# Preventing Scrollable layout when using webview/mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, layout, android-webview

I am stuck in one situation...I have my parent layout as a scrollable layout. Inside this layout, I have a webview and a tablelayout. Some data are inflated in this scrollable layout.

My question is, my vertical scrollable functionality seems to be disabled since my scrollable layout already have the functionality. I hardly can scroll up and down inside the webview. And same situation for Mapview. I can only zoom in and zoom out using horizontal gesture. I wonder if there is any way to disable the scroll functionality only when I zoom in/out, scroll up/down in mapview/webview. Thank you so much.

Comment: what you want....do you want to disable scrollable parent layout?

Comment: yes. I want to disable it temporarily while I am mapview/webview.